# How to use smarty variable inside jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, smarty

Is it possible to use smarty variable inside jquery function ? For example: I have `/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html` and I need to put this lane of code between data brackets in Jquery : `location.href = $(this).data('smarty_code_here');`. Thank you very much.

Jquery:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#about_ats h3 a').click(function(e){
    $(this).attr('href',"/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html"); 
   });
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="about_ats" data-role="collapsible">
     <h3><a href="#">About ATS</a></h3>
</div>
```

Jquery full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
{/literal}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = location.href.split("/")
    var hostname = arr[2];
    var countryCode = arr[3];
    var languageCode = arr[4];

    if(window.location.href == "http://"+hostname+"/"+countryCode+"/"+languageCode+"/" || window.location.href == "http://"+hostname+"/"+countryCode+"/"+languageCode+"/1_reseni-pro-prumyslovou-a-procesni-automatizaci-kvalitu-a-it.html"){
        $('#nav').show();
        $('#nav h4').hide();
        $('#nav h4 a').trigger('click');
    }else{
        $('#nav').hide();
        $('#nav h4').hide();
    }
   $('#languages').hide();
   $('.search').hide();
   $('.contacts').hide();
   $('#menu').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav').slideToggle('300');
    if($("#nav").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {

    }else{
        $('#nav h4 a').trigger('click');    
    }
   }); 
   $('#search_menu').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.search').slideToggle('300');
   });
   $('#globe_menu').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.contacts').slideToggle('300');
    if($(".contacts").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {

    }else{
        $('.contacts h2 a').trigger('click');    
    }
   });
   $('#lang_menu').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#languages').slideToggle('300');
    if($("#languages").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {

    }else{
        $('#languages h4 a').trigger('click');    
    }
   });
   $('#about_ats h3 a').click(function(){
   {/literal}
            alert("/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html"); 
   {literal}
   });
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?
I think 
`location.href = $(this).data('{$smartyVar}');`

Would just work.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. Doesn't work man !

Comment: Then I think something else is wrong. I just tested `$smarty->assign('test', 'test variable'); ` With `<script>
alert('{$test}');
</script>` And that worked.

Is your `<script></script>` in between `{literal}{/literal}` tags?

Comment: show example. Mine code doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you put {literal} tags and where did you close them

Comment: I removed `{literal}` tags, because that didn't work. Try a simple test script like `<script>
alert('{$yourVar}');
</script>`  with your variable.

Comment: When I remove literal in my .tpl then It shows fatal error on page.

Comment: no don't remove all the literal tags in your document. I was just asking if your script was in between literal tags. If so, you should close the literal tag before the script, and open it again after the script.

Comment: I tried this without result: `alert({/literal}"/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html"{literal});`

Comment: that wasn't exactly what I meant. First could you check if your script is actually within the literal tags if so close the literal tag and open it after the complete script `{/literal} <script> alert('{$country}/{$lang}');</script>{literal}` something like that.

Also, check if your code returns any erros, and check your source code to see if it actually returns the variables in the source code.

Comment: when I close my Jquery code iwth literal and start new javascript without literal it shows alert with right smarty variable. Can you help me how to make it work inside Jquery function click. I need to redirect page after click. Like this: `$('#about_us h3 a').click(function(e){
    location.href = $(this).data('{$smartyVar}');  
   });`

Comment: Allright, so we've established that that indeed is the problem. Is it possible to put the `{/literal}` before the complete jQuery? Try adding more code to your original question, then I might be able to produce a  sollution.

Comment: Question updated with more information about my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#about_us h3 a').click(function(e){
            $(this).attr('href',"/{/literal}{$country}/{$lang}{literal}/8_about-ats.html"); 
        });
    });
</script>
{/literal}
```

Edit:
Saw you solved the problem when I wrote my post :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `{literal}` tags in your code.

<strike>{literal}</strike>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#about_us h3 a').click(function(e){
            $(this).attr('href',"/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html"); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

<strike>{/literal}</strike>

Comment: Can I use second document.ready below first </script> ? When I remove literal from first <script> it display fatal error on page.

Comment: Did you also remove the `{/literal}` closing tag? It should work without errors in this form. Also what is the error message, or do you jsut get a blank page?

Comment: Yes I remove both `{literal}` and `{/literal}` and after I removed this tags I get error unrecognized tag on line 30 where is `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Weird. Just tested that code and it works fine here. Does the page get returned? Can you check your source code and see how it is being output at the moment?

Comment: When I close {/literal} just before close `document.ready()` then my jquery works fine and I can use `alert("/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html");` fine but i can't use jquery function click and script doesnt undestand `$(this).attr("href","smarty_variable");`

Comment: Could you include your complete code as is. I'm able to use jquery functions without the use of `{literal}`. so maybe there's something else.

Comment: Try copy pasting my example code exactly. In stead of removing the literal tags yourself. The use of spaces tells Smarty that the script is not a function. Therefore the `{literal`} is not required.

Comment: Alert works after click on link but how to redirect to another page where part of url is that smarty variable `$('#about_ats h3 a').click(function(){
   {/literal}
            alert("/{$country}/{$lang}/8_about-ats.html"); 
   {literal}
   });
});
</script>
{/literal}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><label>{/literal}{$smarty.session.full_name|@ucfirst}{literal}</label></td>";
    data +="<td><input type='text' id='i_tour_date"+i+"' class='se' name='tour_date[]'/></td></tr>";

    $('#sds').append(data);
```

use literal open close tag... work well..............